# SQL Server INSERT … SELECT Statement won't parse

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I get the following error message with SQL Server 2005

> *Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure EPIN, Line 37*
>   *The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The  number of SELECT values must match the
>   number of INSERT columns.*

I have copy and pasted the select list and insert list into excel and verified there are the same number of items in each list. Both tables an additional primary key field with is not listed in either the insert statement or select list. I am not sure if that is relevant, but suspicious it may be.

Here is the source for my stored procedure:

```
 set ANSI_NULLS ON
 set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 go

 -- =============================================
 -- Author:     Kristian Manuel
 -- Create date: 10/3/2012
 -- Description:    
 -- =============================================
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EPIN] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @PLUCODE varchar(30),      --Table tblPolicy
     @ECPAYFEES numeric(18,2),
     @COSTPAYABLE numeric(18,2),
     @RETAILPRICE numeric(18,2),
     @DENOMINATION varchar(50),
     @CARDNAME varchar(50),
     @DistributorID varchar(8),
     @AccntID decimal(18,0)

 --PO1  
 AS
 BEGIN
     -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
     -- interfering with SELECT statements.
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     INSERT INTO [ECPAY-PC].[GENESIS].[dbo].[tblPolicy]
     ( 
       PolicyID                 ,
       AccountTID               ,
       DistributorID            ,
       CARDNAME                 ,
       DENOMINATION             ,
       RETAILPRICE              ,
       COSTPAYABLE              ,
       ECPAYFEES                ,
       PLUCODE 
     ) 
     SELECT 
         t.* 
     FROM
        (SELECT 
            AccountTID = @AccntID, 
            DistributorID = @DistributorID, 
            CARDNAME = @CARDNAME,      
            DENOMINATION = @DENOMINATION, 
            RETAILPRICE = @RETAILPRICE, 
            COSTPAYABLE = @COSTPAYABLE,      
            ECPAYFEES = @ECPAYFEES, 
            PLUCODE = @PLUCODE) t,
        [ECPAY-PC].[ECPNWEB].[dbo].[account] a
     WHERE
        a.AccntID = t.AccountTID --for account
 END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear - your `INSERT` statement expects **9 columns**

```
   1. PolicyID                 
   2. AccountTID               
   3. DistributorID            
   4. CARDNAME                 
   5. DENOMINATION             
   6. RETAILPRICE              
   7. COSTPAYABLE              
   8. ECPAYFEES                
   9. PLUCODE
```

to be filled - but your `SELECT` only provides **8 values**

```
   1. AccountTID               
   2. DistributorID            
   3. CARDNAME                 
   4. DENOMINATION             
   5. RETAILPRICE              
   6. COSTPAYABLE              
   7. ECPAYFEES                
   8. PLUCODE
```

It seems you're **not** providing any value for the `PolicyID` column (first column in yoru `INSERT`) from your `SELECT` statement.....

**Update:** if your `PolicyID` column in your target table is an "auto-increment" (or `IDENTITY`) column - then you **must not** include in in your `INSERT` statement!

Just use this:

```
 INSERT INTO [ECPAY-PC].[GENESIS].[dbo].[tblPolicy]
 (AccountTID, DistributorID, CARDNAME, DENOMINATION,
  RETAILPRICE, COSTPAYABLE, ECPAYFEES, PLUCODE)

    SELECT (that provides those 8 values) ....
```

If you omit the `PolicyID` from your `INSERT` statement, then SQL Server will automatically assign an `identity` value to it and your `INSERT .... SELECT` statement will not work since you're providing 8 values to an `INSERT` which expects 8 columns...

Comment: PolicyID is a Auto Increment column so I did not put it in select ..thanks

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel: in that case, you **MUST NOT** include it in the `INSERT` list either!

Comment: when i delete the Policy Id and execute it works fine but when I run it in the program the error is saying like this cannot insert the value null into column 'PolicyID',table 'GENESIS.dbo.tblplicy;column does not allow nulls.Insert fails.The statement has been terminated..

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel: in that case your **application code** has some problems - not your SQL ... --> new question

Comment: there are no problems with my application code..for my stored procedure I think..for sql server.,

Comment: and that may mean PolicyID is not an Identity column

Comment: thanks it work fine for me now..I set the Policy ID to Identity Column..thanks